# Adaptive flexbox not working for three columns

Tags: css, flexbox

Currently I have three columns in flexbox (current situation in Plunkr).

[image]

When the screen gets small I would like to have the second column to be on top of the other two (desired situation in Plunkr).

[image]

I have created a Plunkr at https://plnkr.co/edit/ZznzRKHvhdISykHP7jNh

Is it possible to get the desired situation by purely modifying the css?

**CSS**

```
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .item {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .item1 {
    flex: 1;
    background: orange;
  }
  .item2 {
    flex: 2;
    background: red;
  }
  .item3 {
    flex: 1;
    background: yellow;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Current situation</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item item1">Foobar1</div>
  <div class="item item2">Foobar2</div>
  <div class="item item3">Foobar3</div>
</div>

<br>

<p>Desired situation with pure css</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item item2">Foobar2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item item1">Foobar1</div>
  <div class="item item3">Foobar3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple flex-wrap and a change of `order` in a media query to bring the second box first in the row order.

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/0srjpka2/6/)

```css
.row {
   display: flex;
   height: 300px;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .item {
   order: 2;
   flex: 1;
 }
 .item1 {
   background: orange;
 }
 .item2 {
   background: red;
   flex:2;
 }
 .item3 {
   background: yellow;
 }
 @media(max-width: 500px) {
   .item2 {
     flex: 100%;
     order: 1;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item item1">Foobar1</div>
  <div class="item item2">Foobar2</div>
  <div class="item item3">Foobar3</div>
</div>
```